# Triggering child jobs and having them check for Perforce changes first?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, perforce

I'm trying to set up a build server for a process we're trying to automate, and have run into an issue that I'm hoping there's an easy fix (or plugin) for.

The end goal is to have a set of jobs that each check for changes in a small subset of our Perforce depot, and then perform a task. The issue is that each of these tasks requires the entire depot in order to execute properly, and since the depot is so large (30+GB) and there are so many of these tasks (50+), actually duplicating the depot and syncing it would be an extreme waste of disk space and network bandwidth.

Instead, I'd like to have one "master" job that deals with syncing the depot (which all the child jobs share), and then have each child job use their own workspace and the "Preview Check Only" populate option in the Jenkins Perforce plugin (which syncs with `p4 sync -k`). Each child job's workspace would then exist only for the job to be able to detect when changes it is interested in have happened, after which they would run their tasks from inside the "master" workspace depot, and everything should just work!

Except I have not been able to figure out how to trigger the child jobs AND have them check for changes to their local workspace before deciding to run. Is there any way to have the children run all the checks they would normally run (if they were just scheduled to run every once in a while) when triggered by another job?

Or maybe there's a better way to do what I'm trying to do? Something that would allow me to share a single Perforce depot, but have child jobs that only run when part of that depot changes? There will also be more child jobs created over time, so being able to set them up and configure them easily would also be a nice thing to have.

Comment: Would it be an option to let Perforce trigger the right jobs in a commit-trigger script?

Comment: We'd rather not use Perforce triggers for this, as doing so would require us going through our company's IT department for every single change we wanted to make. Not fun.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out a solution here, but it's pretty convoluted. Here goes!

The master job does the Perforce sync, and then runs a batch script that uses curl to run a polling of each child job: `curl -X POST http://jenkins/view/Job/polling`. When the child jobs have `Poll SCM` enabled (but do not have a schedule set), this lets them poll the SCM when the receive the polling request from the web API. Kinda messy, but it works!